# Finding $\lambda$ for poisson random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm probably over thinking this, but a question states that there are $3.5$ commercial airline plane crashes per year. What's the probability that there are at least $2$ such accidents next month?

For my answer I put that since this is a poisson random variable, we can calculate this by letting $X$ be the number of plane crashes next month. Then:

$$P\{X\ge 2\}=1-(P\{X=0 \}+P\{X=1\})$$

Then I thought since the equation is $P\{X=i\}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}$ we'd want to take $\lambda $ to be $3.5/12=.29$, since they are asking for next month, not year, giving:

$$P\{X\ge2\}= 1-e^{-.29}-.29e^{-.29}$$

But the answer uses $\lambda=3.5$ instead.

> Why is this?

Comment: Where did you get the answer which you hold in such high esteem? It seems wrong to me. If your unit of time is a month, $\lambda$ should be $3.5/12$, which gives $P\{X\ge2\} \sim 0.03$, whereas $\lambda = 3.5$ gives $0.864$ which is a little ridiculous. I'm going to say that you're correct.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod: It's from my professors solution. Yeah I thought it was a little strange...

Comment: If you have quoted the problem correctly, you are right. No question, no doubt. Of course there are certain implicit assumptions, that the basic axioms that lead to the Poisson are (nearly enough) satisfied. The same would not hold for drowning accidents, which, in northern latitudes at least, exhibit strong seasonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of not leaving this question unanswered:

If the question stated that there were $3.5$ crashes *monthly*, $\lambda$ would therefore be $3.5$. But as it stands, with $3.5$ crashes yearly $\lambda=3.5/12 
\sim  .29$. And the answer follows from above.